# Primality test based on initial conditions alone.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m=252601$. Suppose we discover that
$$3^{126300} ≡ 67772 \pmod{252601}$$
$$3^{252600} ≡ 1\pmod{252601}$$
Is then $252601$ prime? composite? Or can we not decide for sure from the information given?

Comment: $(2k+1)\mid(3^k - E)$ and $2k\mid(3^{2k}-1)$

Comment: relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv \pm 1\pmod p$ for any prime $p$ and a positive integer $a$ smaller than $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\,252601\mid 67772^2\!-1 = (67772-1)(67772+1)\ \Rightarrow\ \gcd(252601, 67772\pm1) > 1.$

In fact $\ \gcd(252601, 67772\!+\!1) = 41,\ \ \gcd(252601, 67772\!-\!1) = 6161,\ \ 41\cdot 6161 = 252601.$

Finding nontrivial square roots of $\,1\,$ is the key idea behind many integer factorization algorithms.